# Clone elastic search index with all mappings

Tags: elasticsearch-5

I’m trying to clone an elastic search index from staging to prod environment. Couldn’t find a way to do it. All I want to do is to clone the existing index with mappings but not the data.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There's no 1-liner for that but this will work if you have the [elasticsearch-python module](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) and you only care about the mappings.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

eshost = <YOUR ELASTICSEARCH HOST>
oldindex = <SOURCE INDEX TO COPY>
newindex = <NEW INDEX>

es = Elasticsearch(eshost)

createReply = es.indices.create(index=newindex)
getReplySource = es.indices.get_mapping(index=oldindex)

sourceMappings = getReplySource[oldindex]['mappings']
for doc_type, mapping in sourceMappings.iteritems():
  putReplyTarget = es.indices.put_mapping(doc_type, mapping, newindex)
```

Comment: This worked for me but iteritems() needs to be replace with items()

Answer (score 1):

In `elasticsearch 5.6` and `py-elasticsearch 5.5.3`, below code works for me:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch("your es url")

old_mapping = es.indices.get_mapping('old_index')

es.indices.create(index='new_index') 
es.indices.put_mapping(index='new_index', doc_type='type name', body=old_mapping['old_index'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, there is the Elasticsearch [Clone index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/indices-clone-index.html) and you can use the Python client to do [`es.indices.clone(source, target)`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/api.html?highlight=clone#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.clone).